# jquery: change input val basend on parent div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some drag and sortable ul's ....
now i need to set the **hidden input field "area[]" value to** the same value of the **ul attribute location**

```
<ul id='sortlistThree' location='1' class='connectMe sort'>
  <li>
    <form class='sort'>
        <input type='hidden' name='area[]' class='dienstplan' data='getform' value='' />
    </form>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form class='sort'>
        <input type='hidden' name='area[]' class='dienstplan' data='getform' value='' />
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id='sortlistThree' location='2' class='connectMe sort'>
  <li>
    <form class='sort'>
        <input type='hidden' name='area[]' class='dienstplan' data='getform' value='' />
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id='sortlistThree' location='3' class='connectMe sort'>
  <li>
    <form class='sort'>
        <input type='hidden' name='area[]' class='dienstplan' data='getform' value='' />
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery you can do it like this, I removed `hidden` so you could see what is going on.

```js
$('input[name="area[]"]').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('value',$(this).closest('ul').attr('location'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='sortlistThree' location='1' class='connectMe sort'>
  <li>
    <form class='sort'>
        <input name='area[]' class='dienstplan' data='getform' value='1' />
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id='sortlistThree' location='2' class='connectMe sort'>
  <li>
    <form class='sort'>
        <input  name='area[]' class='dienstplan' data='getform' value='1' />
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id='sortlistThree' location='3' class='connectMe sort'>
  <li>
    <form class='sort'>
        <input  name='area[]' class='dienstplan' data='getform' value='1' />
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `.parents()`, because [*.parents()* will add **every** ancestor up to the root, while *.closest()* stops as soon as it finds a match](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#entry-longdesc)

Comment: And if you change `$('input').each(` to `$('input[name="area[]"]').each(`, you don't need the if-clause

Comment: Ow, and you forgot the `;` at the end of your code (ow, and at the end of the line as well, guess that's just your preferred style of coding, sorry to be a ballbuster:D)

Comment: Thank you guys! Works great!

Comment: @myfunkyside I apprichiate constructive comments :)